# How to fix JSON parse error: Unexpected indentifier "object" in React Native?

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native, rss, rss-reader

I use Axios to fetch from a rss2json api. I use Hooks to parse the response.data from Axios into a feed. Now I want to parse that feed into react-native-deck-swiper swiper component but I get the error "How to fix JSON parse error: Unexpected indentifier "object" in React Native?".
How can I fix this?

```
const URL = "https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url= THE WEBSITE RSS FEED";
const PROXY = "https://api.allorigins.win/raw?url=";

let content = null;
const [feed, setFeed] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(URL)
            .then(response => {
                setFeed(response.data)
            })
    }, [URL])

if(feed) {
        content = 
        <Swiper 
            cards={feed}
            cardIndex={index}
            renderCard={(card) => {
                 <View><Image source={{uri: feed.items[0].thumbnail}}} /></View>
                }}
        ></Swiper>
    }

return (
   <View>{content}</View>
);
```

Libraries: react-native-deck-swiper, axios
I use rss2json.com to convert my rss feed into json and then use Axios to fetch it.

EDIT:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We too have faced this issue before. Even if the data is proper json it was returning the data sometimes in string. We are doing something like this

```
axios.get(URL)
.then(response => {
  let responseData = response.data
  const responseJson = (typeof responseData == "string" ? JSON.parse(responseData.trim()) : responseData);
  setFeed(responseJson)
})
```

Can you try loading the swiper like this:

```
<View>
  {
      feed && <Swiper 
            cards={feed}
            cardIndex={index}
            renderCard={(card) => {
                 <View><Image source={{uri: feed.items[0].thumbnail}} /></View>
                }}
        ></Swiper>
  }
  </View>
```

Comment: there's no error now but my Swiper component is still not rendering

Comment: Error: unexpected token

Comment: Can you check the edited answer, I included a screen shot after trying to loading the swiper like you show me

Comment: oops, sorry, brainfarts :v, but after i removed the extra } the swiper is still not rendering

Comment: Remove the extra curly brace it should be <View><Image source={{uri: feed.items[0].thumbnail}} /></View>. Edited my answer as well

Answer (score 0):

try this way ;)

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(URL)
       .then(response => {
          // items ==> [{thumbnail: "", ... },{thumbnail: "", ... },{thumbnail: "", ... }]
          const { items } = response.data
          setFeed(items)
    })
}, [URL])


        
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        {
          feed && <Swiper 
            cards={feed}
            cardIndex={index}
            renderCard={(card) => {
                <View style={styles.card}>
                  <Image 
                    style={styles.cardImage} 
                    source={{uri: card.thumbnail}} />
                </View>
            }}
        ></Swiper>
      }
    </View>
  );
```

Comment: nevermind, thank you for your time once again, I'll use another library